# Vue 3 TypeScript - Problem with `App.vue` in `main.ts` and Tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using TypeScript with Vue and I'm facing this error from my `main.ts` file.

[image: Error Information]

Here's my `shims-vue.d.ts` file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module "*.vue" {
    import type { DefineComponent } from "vue";
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
    export default component;
}
```

My `App.vue` is just a simple template without any `script` or `style`:

```
<template lang="pug">
router-view
</template>
```

I do not want to do the `"noImplicitAny": false` in `tsconfig.js`, so is there any solution to this problem apart from that?

Also, same thing happens in test cases,

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Layout from "@/plugin/layout/Layout.vue";

describe("Layout.vue", () => {
    it("renders props.msg when passed", () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Layout);
        expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch("sidebar");
    });
});
```

Error is:
[image]

Comment: Does the error occur only inside tests? What command do you run to get error? `vue-cli build` or `vue-cli test`?

Comment: Did you try to add script to App? They aren't necessarily the same errors, it could be that Jest can't resolve `@/`

Comment: This problem appears in both `App.vue` while starting the app in development environment, and while running the tests using `vue-cli-service test:unit`.

Comment: And I tried with the relative path as well instead of `@`, that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Do you have `webpack.config.js` in your project?

Comment: No, I think `vue.config.json` handles it, probably has some options that are passed to WebPack

Comment: My `vue.config.json` is empty basically, it's just `module.exports={}`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you named your vue file `App.vue.js`.

The solution: **rename `App.vue.js` to `App.vue`**

Comment: No, the file name is `App.vue` only. I'm not sure why the `App.vue.js` error comes.

Comment: Ah, that was my mistake. Sure, webpack aliases the file to *.vue.js